# Negative phases don;t exist for 1s orbital why?

Tags: physical-chemistry

[image][image][!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgpWD.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgpWD.jpg)

**what is the dot on the two s orbitals?**

**IF NEGATIVE PHASE DOESN'T EXIST WHAT IS THE S ORBITAL IN BLUE IN THE FIRST PIC?**

Comment: Short answer: the dot is the nucleus (not to scale). The negative phase is a result of LCAO (linear combination of atomic orbitals) with a negative coefficient. The two different phases contained on one orbital for p and higher is something else entirely.

Answer (score 4):

A $1s$ orbital can have either positive or negative phase.  Which it is, is our label: all the experimentally accessible features are the same with either choice.

Now consider two such orbitals.  Either one can have either phase, but there is one more factor:  the relative relationship between the signs of the phases.  They can combine with the same sign to produce a bonding orbital, which is the same bonding orbital whether we render the common sign positive or negative.  Or they can assume opposite signs and combine to make an antibonding orbital; this orbital is the same whether the first orbital is positive and the second negative, or vice versa.  All the experimentally accessible information is dependent on *relative signs* of the contributions to a molecular orbital, not how we render the absolute sign of any orbital.